# Can I get a HTML element by ID in a POST message (Tornado webserver)?

Tags: tornado

This is how I get the value of a HTML element by the name of the HTML element:

```
self.get_argument('name')
```

Can I get an elements by ID?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use "self.get_argument('name')" in Tornado to get the Parameters supplied by the GET-Request URL, I don't think there is a way to get elements by id.

If you want that you should add it to the GET Request.

Comment: It means that the name of the HTML which I want to get at the server side, must be unique?

Comment: yes, what you submit with the "name"-Attribite anyways.